How to restart a Python script from within itself?
There seem to be at least two ways to restart a Python script. What's the difference between these two ways, and when to use which? Thanks a lot!
One way:
import sys
import os

def restart_script():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)

def main():
    print("Starting script...")
    try:
        # Some code
        # For demonstration, simulate an error
        raise ValueError("Simulated error occurred!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        print("Restarting script...")
        restart_script()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Another way:
import os
import sys
import time
import subprocess

def main():
    while True:
        print("Starting program")
        try:
            p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'my_program.py'])
            p.wait()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
            print("Restarting program...")
            time.sleep(5)  # Delay before restarting to avoid rapid restarts
        else:
            print("Program exited without error")
            break  # Exit the loop if the program exits without error

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


The real question is: why would you ever need to? Because using a monitor utility that restarts a script when it errors out makes way more sense than trying to make a script start a new copy of itself before shutting itself down. Just have it keep running while actually catching and logging errors so you can gracefully recover? (or really shut down if the error is so important that your script should under no circumstance get restarted and instead a human should be notified to look at what the heck just happened)

When there is an error, I would like to restart, e.g., to release a file so that the wrong file can be deleted and a new one can be generated after the script is restarted. Without restarting, the file is still used by the process and it is not possible to remove the file and generate a new one.

Definitely use a monitor (like watchdog, py-mon or even nodemon or pm2, both of which can run "anything", not just node)

Script type #1 restarts itself. Script type #2 has two parts: the actual script and a parent monitoring the running process. I'm writing script type, because the actual code may have some issues, e.g. the second script does not check the exit code.
The process running script #1 is always the same (same PID). It could leak resources. A bigger problem is that it could be killed and then it disappears.
Obviously, type #2 is much more robust. The parent is few lines long and can be easily verified. If you need just a restart, use something like that. Perhaps add an exponential backoff to increase the delay for consecutive failures.
On Linux, see how systemd can help you. It has a fine-grained control over how to restart, when to restart, what delay, how many times attempts, etc.
